# How do I change Random Forest code from formula interface to matrix interface?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

This is probably a very quick, and easy question.  I've read that changing code from the formula interface, to matrix interface significantly improves run times.

My current code is as follows:

```
randomForest(linear_weight ~ ., data = df, importance = T)
```

How do I change this code to a matrix interface using `randomForest`?

Is it as simple as doing this?

```
randomForest(df, linear_weight, importance = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for using the `x=` and `y=` input, below is not knowing your dataframe, and assuming all your independent variables are numeric and not categorical:

```
X_train = as.matrix(df[,setdiff(colnames(df),"linear_weight")])
y_train = df$linear_weight
```

If you have categorical, then:

```
X_train = model.matrix(linear_weight ~ .,data=df)
```

After which:

```
randomForest(x = X_train, 
             y = y_train, importance = TRUE)
```

I think it really depends on your data. Also in the event you have categorical variables, if you factor in the time to convert it into a dense matrix, I am not sure  it goes faster

Comment: I believe this is correct.  My data I'm testing has only numerical variables.  When I changed it using your code, it actually took longer when I tested using tictoc.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I tested it briefly... don't see a huge difference. In my experience, it makes a difference when using `ranger` plus you have quite some categorical data